# Update test case outcome status in azure test plans based on robot framework result file

Tags: azure-devops, robotframework

Currently we are using Xray Test Management to create, define and execute test cases. We automated them with Robot Framework and import the test results via Xray Rest API. Afterwards the related test execution and the related test cases are updated in their status according to the outcome in the Robot Framework result file. Is there also a similar feature (or app in marketplace) in Azure Test plan? So that we can import our test results from Robot Framework to Azure Test Plans and connect it to an existing test plan?

Thanks,

Andreas

Comment: Hello, did you get any workaround for this?

Comment: Hello, no. Since there is no feature in Azure Test plan you would have to call rest api endpoint of Azure Test plan. Up to know we haven't implemented it since the change was not triggered until now.